# Enums, Constructor overloads with similar conversions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, enums, constructor-overloading

Why does VisualC++ (2008) get confused 'C2666: 2 overloads have similar conversions' when I specify an enum as the second parameter, but not when I define a bool type?

Shouldn't type matching already rule out the second constructor because it is of a 'basic_string' type?

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

enum EMyEnum { mbOne, mbTwo };
class test {
public: 
#if 1 // 0 = COMPILE_OK, 1 = COMPILE_FAIL
    test(basic_string<char> myString, EMyEnum myBool2) { }
    test(bool myBool, bool myBool2) { }
#else
    test(basic_string<char> myString, bool myBool2) { }
    test(bool myBool, bool myBool2) { }
#endif
};

void testme() {
    test("test", mbOne);
}
```

I can work around this by specifying a reference 'ie. basic_string &myString' but not if it is 'const basic_string &myString'.

Also calling explicitly via "test((basic_string)"test", mbOne);" also works.

I suspect this has something to do with every expression/type being resolved to a bool via an inherent '!=0'.

Curious for comments all the same :)

Comment: One of the best descriptions of overload resolution can be found in Appendix B of [C++ Templates:  The Complete Guide](http://www.amazon.com/Templates-Complete-Guide-David-Vandevoorde/dp/0201734842).  The rest of the book is excellent, too, but that appendix makes for a very succinct and easy to reference listing of the overload resolution rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the ambiguity is that one candidate function is better than another candidate function only if none of its parameters are a worse match than the parameters of the other.

The problem is that the string literal, which has a type of `const char[5]` is convertible to both `std::string` (via a converting constructor) and to a `bool` (since an array can decay to a pointer, and any pointer is implicitly convertible to `bool`).  The conversion to `bool` is preferred because it is a standard conversion and standard conversions are preferred to user-defined conversions.

So, consider the "broken" overloads:

```
test(basic_string<char> myString, EMyEnum myBool2) { }  // (1)
test(bool myBool, bool myBool2) { }                     // (2)
```

The first argument is a `const char[5]` and prefers `(2)` (per the description above).  The second argument is an `EMyEnum` and prefers `(1)`, which is an exact match; a conversion would be required to match `(2)` (an enumeration can be implicitly converted to a `bool`).

Now consider the second case:

```
test(basic_string<char> myString, bool myBool2) { }    // (3)
test(bool myBool, bool myBool2) { }                    // (4)
```

The first argument still prefers `(4)`, but now the second argument can match both `(3)` and `(4)` equally.  So, the compiler can select `(4)` and there is no ambiguity.

There would be no ambiguity if you eliminated the required conversion for the first argument, e.g.,

```
test(basic_string<char>("test"), mbOne);
```

because both arguments would match `(1)` exactly.